# Javascript/Jquery: validate input with a number range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to validate an input field within a preconfigured range of numbers.
Only numbers from 1 up to 24 are allowed.

How can I do?

---

With a custom solution like this:

```
    $('.field').keypress(function(event) {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val()) + HERE_I_SHOULD_SUM_THE_NEWLY_ADDED_DIGIT;
        if(val < 1 || val > 24) event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I'm able to retrieve the current input value.
How can I add the newly added digit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
​$("input").on("change", function() {
    var val = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value, 10) || 1);
    this.value = val > 25 ? 24 : val;
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3jw4S/

Comment: @MichDart What do you mean by *doesn't work*? Have you checked the demo? Do you consider that `change` event runs only when input element loses focus? If you need immediate reaction, then try `keyup` event: http://jsfiddle.net/3jw4S/1/.

Comment: Yes, It works when the input loses focus. Is it possible to change this behaviour to handle a keypress event? thanks

Comment: Perfect! Just a little fix to this line: $(this).val(val > 24 ? 24 : val);

Answer (score 2):

There are builtin functionalities for inputs in modern browsers:

A comprehensive overview can be found here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Basically, you could write:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" required>
```

with pattern you can define regular expressions to test against:

```
pattern="\d[0-3]"
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EDnYZ/1/)**

Comment: I know, but I need some fallbacks

Comment: @MichDart then define these attributes and evaluate them with javascript if the browser can't handle it. Thats the best solution.

Comment: @MichDart i updated the fiddle, this should be the way to go to be compatible to medern browser without leaving the old ones behind.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for JQuery that can help you with validation called Valid8:

http://unwrongest.com/projects/valid8/

You will need to use a regular expression such as this one:

```
^([1-9]|[1]?[1-9]?|[2][0-4]|10)$
```

Comment: And this is true for 0... sorry ;)

Comment: That's also a great solution. However, I need a more immediate reaction.

Comment: I'm *really* not meaning to be a dick but the current edit returns false for 10. For a numeric range its probably easier to cast the value to an integer for numeric comparison.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't used regular expressions in years so I'm trying to get back in the game.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x <1|| x >24)
  {
  alert("Value must be between 1 & 24");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Something along those lines should work

Comment: I cannot submit the form. I'm working with ajax. Is it possible to check for validation during input insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function validate() {
 var x = parseInt(value,10) // its the value from the input box;
 if(isNaN(x)||x<1||x>24)
 {
  alert("Value must be between 1 and 24");
  return false;
  }
}
```